# прогресс бар должен запустится только когда появится в экране при прокрутке страницы

Tags: javascript, progress-bar

```js
//при загрузке
    window.onscroll = function(e) {
      e = window.pageYOffset;
      if (e >= 100) {
        move();
      }

      function move() {
        var pBar_line = document.getElementById('progress__bar-line');
        var width = 10;
        var interval = setInterval(frame, 10);

        function frame() {
          if (width >= 73) {
            clearInterval(interval);
          } else {
            width++;
            pBar_line.style.width = width + '%';
            document.getElementById('label').innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
          }
      }

   }

}
```

```css
.box{
  height: 500px;
  padding-top: 200px;
}
      
#progress__bar {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  height: 5px;
  background: grey;
}

#progress__bar-line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div><span id="label">10%</span></div>
  <div id="progress__bar">
    <div id="progress__bar-line"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: что значит "повторяется постоянно"? загрузите изображение, демонстрирующее это

Comment: https://codepen.io/mario-web/pen/LzyaRv вот ссылка, при проркутке постоянно срабатывает скролбар, а надо чтобы один раз

Comment: в премере выше изменил, теперь можно увидеть ошибку

Answer (score 1):

Я немного изменил ваш пример, анимацию на *js* заменил на *css*.

В вашем примере скроллбар постоянно повторялся, потому что при каждом событии `onscroll` переменная `width` инициализировалась заново со значением **10**.

Пример на [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OxgyJV).

```js
window.onload = function() {
  window.onscroll = onScroll;
  onScroll();

  function onScroll() {
    var pageY = +window.pageYOffset;
    console.log();
    var percent = Math.min(Math.ceil(
      pageY / (document.body.clientHeight - window.innerHeight) * 100
    ), 100);
    var pBar_line = document.getElementById("progress__bar-line");
    var pBar_label = document.getElementById("progress__bar-label");
    pBar_line.style.width = percent + "%";
    pBar_label.innerText = percent + "%";
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  height: 3000px;
}

#progress__bar {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 5px;
  background: grey;
  top: 0;
}

#progress__bar-line {
  position: relative;
  width: 1%;
  height: 5px;
  background: green;
  transition: width ease 600ms;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="progress__bar">
    <div id="progress__bar-line"></div>
    <div>ui/ux design <span id="progress__bar-label">1%</span></div>
  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: а как это изменить ?

Comment: тут прогресс бар на прокрутку действует, надо наоборот, при скролле до высоты например 500 срабатывает прогресс бар ЕДИНОЖЫ, и все.

Comment: @Mario отредактируйте ваш вопрос, что бы было более понятно, чего вы хотите. Опишите желаемое поведение.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onscroll = function (e) {
  var e = pageYOffset;
  e = parseInt(e);

  if (e == 650 && e < 652) {
    move();
  }
}
```

нашел вот такое решение пока что, не уверен что она правильное, но работает

Comment: Это бред какой-то, а не решение...

Comment: может подскажите/напишите как правильно ? я не силен в js

Comment: Так тут соседний ответ есть - вроде выглядит правдоподобно.